# header() refirect not working on Ajax Login

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to login with ajax. The script is working well and I am getting logged in but I am not getting redirected to the `dashboard.php` file. Codes are given below. Please try to help me out.

Ajax call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var dataString = {
            username: $("#username").val(),
      password: $("#password").val(),
        };
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "login-process.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: true,
      beforeSend: function(){
        $('#loading-image').show();
      },
      complete: function(){
        $('#loading-image').hide();
      },
      success: function(html){
        $('.message').html(html).fadeIn(500);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

login-process.php

```
<?php
include'config/db.php';
$msg = null;
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$uname  = (!empty($_POST['username']))?$_POST['username']:null;
$pass   = (!empty($_POST['password']))?$_POST['password']:null;

if($_POST){
    $stmt = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE mem_uname = :uname";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($stmt);
    $stmt->bindValue(':uname', $uname);
    $stmt->execute();
    $checklgn = $stmt->rowCount();
    $fetch = $stmt->fetch();

    if($checklgn > 0){
        if(password_verify($pass, $fetch['mem_pass'])){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['sanlogin'] = $fetch['mem_id'];
            $msg = "<div class='message-success'>Access Granted! Please wait...</div>";
            $go_login = header("refresh:2; url=dashboard.php");
        }else{
            $msg = "<div class='message-error'>Password mismatch. Please try again!</div>";
        }
    }else{
        $msg = "<div class='message-error'>User not found. Please try again!</div>";
    }
}
echo $msg;
echo $go_login;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use AJAX to log in, you must use javascript to redirect. Redirecting PHP will only result in the AJAX call being redirected which doesn't produce the desired result.

In your `success` clause of the ajax request you can add `window.location.replace("dashboard.php");`

Comment: and if I want it to refresh in 2 seconds then how to set the timer?

Comment: Use `setTimeout` to delay the call (2000ms = 2 seconds).
`setTimeout(function(){ window.location.replace("dashboard.php"); }, 2000);`

Comment: its redirecting to dashboard even if I enter incorrect username and password. How can I add a check to check if to redirect only on login success?

Comment: There are many ways, You can make the AJAX request fail upon entering a wrong password. Or you could add it to the data you return and check for that condition.

In this case it would be if the response from the ajax call does not contain "message-error", then redirect, otherwise: don't.

Comment: Okay so how can I get to check on `message-error` response? Like here I am getting everything wrapped in `.html(html)`. How can I catch it to add on if...else statement? A code example please..

Answer (score 0):

In you ajax `success:`

use `window.location.href="/uri/to/redirect";`

```
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href="/uri/to/redirect";
},2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `header` PHP function in this situation.
You should redirect in your $.ajax function like this:

1) You should return JSON in your `login-process.php`:

```
...

$result = array();
if($_POST){
    $stmt = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE mem_uname = :uname";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($stmt);
    $stmt->bindValue(':uname', $uname);
    $stmt->execute();
    $checklgn = $stmt->rowCount();
    $fetch = $stmt->fetch();

    if($checklgn > 0){
        if(password_verify($pass, $fetch['mem_pass'])){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['sanlogin'] = $fetch['mem_id'];
            $result = array(
                'msg' => "<div class='message-success'>Access Granted! Please wait...</div>",
                'redirect' => 'dashboard.php',
            );
        }else{
            $result = array(
                'msg' => "<div class='message-error'>Password mismatch. Please try again!</div>",
            );
        }
    }else{
        $result = array(
            'msg' => "<div class='message-error'>User not found. Please try again!</div>",
        );
    }
}

echo json_encode($result);
exit;
```

2) You should add parameter `dataType` into your `$.ajax` call and process attribute `redirect` of the server answer (if this attribute exists):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        var dataString = {
            username: $("#username").val(),
            password: $("#password").val(),
        };
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json', // <-- set expected dataType here
            type: "POST",
            url: "login-process.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: true,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#loading-image').show();
            },
            complete: function () {
                $('#loading-image').hide();
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('.message').html(data.message).fadeIn(500);

                // if we have attribute "redirect" in answer
                if(typeof data.redirect !== 'undefined'){
                    // redirect here after 2 seconds
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        document.location.href = data.redirect;
                    },2000);
                }

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```